# How do I get a button element for a sliding navigation panel to rotate with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Basically, I have an html page where I have set up a sliding panel when you click the square. How do I get the square to rotate 180 degrees when I click it? I can only manage to have the button trigger the div sliding or the the button spinning, but not both at the same time. I noticed it has something to do with how I'm placing the input tag. If it's inside the label, the button rotates but there is no effect on the panel. If it's outside of the label, pressing the square triggers the side panel. Been going at this all day but can't seem to figure it out. Ideally, I would have liked to get a arrow in place of the square but I wouldn't know where to start...

-sliding div:
https://codepen.io/yung_terminal/pen/oWrZZj

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-wrap">
 <input id="slide-sidebar" type="checkbox" role="button" />
 <label for="slide-sidebar">
 <div class="tab"></div>
 </label>

 <div class="content">

 </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar {
background-color: white;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
#navpan {
position: absolute;
right: 120px;
bottom: 740px;
}
.sidebar li{
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
}
.content {
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 190px;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;  
-moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

input:checked ~ .content{ 
left: 0;
}

input:checked ~ label {
left: 0;
}

label {
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 190px;
background-color: 0;
font-size:60px;
-moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

.tab {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: white;
transition: all 0.75s 0.25s;
transform: rotate(0);
}

#slide-sidebar:checked + .tab{
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code. Please check it. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/7873/). I added `onclick` function to that box and created `rotated` class. Using css I rotate that box with 90degree.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rotate').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('rotated');
});
});
```

```css
.rotated { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.sidebar {
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#navpan {
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  bottom: 740px;
}
.sidebar li{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.content {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 190px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
   display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .content{ 
    left: 0;
}
input:checked ~ label {
    left: 0;
}
label {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 190px;
    background-color: 0;
    font-size:60px;
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
.tab {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 0.75s 0.25s; 
}
#slide-sidebar:checked + .tab{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrap">
      <input id="slide-sidebar" type="checkbox" role="button" />
      <label for="slide-sidebar">
        <div class="tab" id="rotate"></div>
      </label>
  <div class="content">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque nulla accusamus illo a dolorum quo, maxime fuga ea nam quae ab deserunt quas distinctio culpa recusandae assumenda quisquam repellendus, perferendis!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include a description of what you have changed. This will make it clear as to why your solution works and the OP's doesn't.

Comment: Updated my answer @JonP. :)

Comment: Now you should note that you have introduced two things that the OP has not asked for, javascript **and** jquery. The OP is afterr a CSS / HTML only option if possible.

Comment: okay @JonP I fixed the issue using css, but you already submit the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but not quite there.

You need to change : `#slide-sidebar:checked + .tab`

To: `#slide-sidebar:checked + label>.tab`

In your initial selector, you are expecting `.tab` to be a sibling of the `checkbox`. The `label` is the sibling with `.tab` being a child of `label`.

```css
.rotated { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.sidebar {
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#navpan {
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  bottom: 740px;
}
.sidebar li{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.content {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 190px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
   display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .content{ 
    left: 0;
}
input:checked ~ label {
    left: 0;
}
label {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 190px;
    background-color: 0;
    font-size:60px;
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
.tab {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 0.75s 0.25s; 
}
#slide-sidebar:checked + label>.tab{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
      <input id="slide-sidebar" type="checkbox" role="button" />
      <label for="slide-sidebar">
        <div class="tab" id="rotate"></div>
      </label>
  <div class="content">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque nulla accusamus illo a dolorum quo, maxime fuga ea nam quae ab deserunt quas distinctio culpa recusandae assumenda quisquam repellendus, perferendis!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` denotes an immediate sibling, which `.tab` is not but `label` wrapping `.tab` is. So change

```
#slide-sidebar:checked + .tab{
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

to

```
#slide-sidebar:checked + label .tab{
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```